# Can't run MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

when I debug mvc application , its show following error.but application build successfully .

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error ASP.NET application
>   initialization failed.
>
> Detailed Error Information: Module
>   AspNetAppInitializationFailureModule Notification    BeginRequest
>   Handler      ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0 Error Code
>   0x00000000

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what was the url you were trying to hit?

Comment: I get this too with a new .net mvc web app from template. Builds but will not browse to default page /Home/Index